# Structs: what should go a header and what should go in the source?

Tags: c

If I have a source file `mystruct.c` and a corresponding header file, what is the proper way to define it in each file?

assume I have a structure:

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    int a;
} MyStruct;
```

should it be placed like this in the header? or should it look more like this:

source file:

```
struct my_struct {
    int a;
};
```

header file:

```
typedef struct my_struct MyStruct;
```

I have the same question about enums and unions.

Im basically looking for the standard way of defining these things so that they can be used in many other files without having to worry about redefinition errors.

Comment: This cannot be answered in general. It depends on where you need the declarations. As a general rule: put into the header files what has to be there and leave in the source file what can be left there.

Comment: If you want all files to be able to directly access the fields of the struct then the first way is the correct way to do it. The second way will not work for that case as the files that include the header will not know about the struct fields (unless you define the struct in every source file). The second method is still valid for a different use case - opaque definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the contents of your struct in the .c file and just declaring the struct to exist in the header means that you need to provide a function to create the struct, e.g.

```
rc = my_struct_create(&s);
```

It has the advantage that you can change the contents of your struct without having to recompile dependent code - this is because the struct is opaque, the only way to create it is with your function and the only way to access any members of the struct will be through functions you define.

I'd personally recommend that approach for library code. Otherwise it really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So is this analogous to private and public for OOP languages? stuff in the header is public and stuff in the source is private? I have heard that classes in c++ are just structures with functions... on a very basic level, is this how private and public fields are implemented?

Comment: Yes, essentially with an opaque struct you have only private members and a struct with a full definition you have public members.

Comment: If you use inline functions, this is not useable. Or if you implement an OOP approach.

Answer (score 0):

In the .h file, you would put the structure definition, and the function prototypes:

**point.h**

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} point;

point *initpt(int, int);
```

In the .c file, you would implement the functions:

**point.c**

```
point *initpt(int x, int y)
{
    point *p;

    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the structure members are part of the public API or not. If the users of the API are not supposed to access the structure members, leave the structure definition to the .c file only. If they are supposed to know the implementation of the structure (for example because you want to allow them to access the members of the structure) put the structure definition in the .h. By principle be more restrictive first, and then if you have too, you can still change it later.